# Can You help me with my english?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, perfect-aspect

Is It correct to say: "I had been his wife before he got married with her."?

Comment: It’s not incorrect.  But why not “I was his previous wife.”

Comment: In German, you get married *with* her. In Russian, you get married *on* her while she gets married *behind* you. In English, we don't do any of these silly things. In English, you get married *to* her. And she gets married *to* you.

Comment: As an aside, "english" is the spin you put on the ball in billiards or golf. We can help you with that, but not on this site. On this site, we can only help you with "English". Which is an entirely different thing. Just like "may" is an entirely different thing from "May", "march" is not the same thing as "March", and "august" is something else than "August".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using the past perfect progressive aspect, [had been] you are indicating that something had happened up to that point which is now completed. It is correct, but the sentence structure is a little... Off...